# How do you match a dollar range value with a regular expression?

Tags: regex

How do you match a dollar range value with a regular expression?

What I have so far matches a single dollar value, such as: `$100`, `$1,000,123`, or `$1,234`

```
[\$]((\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)|\d{1,3})
```

But, what if I want to ALSO match a range value like:  `$100 - $3,000`  or `$1,000-$5,000`

Can anyone help me with this?  I don't know how to match the optional dash character with an additional value, with or without space char padding.

Comment: what is your input and what do you want as a result?

Comment: You can use something like this: "a(-b)?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
[\$]((\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)|\d{1,3})((\s)?-(\s)?[\$]((\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)|\d{1,3}))?
```

Comment: It worked.  Thank you!  Although the existence of spaces next to the dash is required.  I can figure out the rest of it.

Comment: @djangofan What about now?

Comment: Yes, that worked.  I really appreciate it.  It was hard for me to find the documentation of how the ? thing works.

Comment: You can shorten your pattern if you remove uneeded parenthesis, and if you write `\$` instead of `[\$]`

Comment: This alternation `|\d{1,3}` is useless too, since you use `(,\d{3})*` before.